# Eclipse causes BlueScreen in Windows 7

Tags: windows, eclipse

Whenever I work in eclipse on Windows 7, during passing to sleep mode, windows Blue Screen is appeared. I can't understand why that happens always while working with eclipse. Any idea will be very helpful.

> Windows error message

```
Error signature:
  Error event name: BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Local ID: 1055

Extra informations about the error:
  BCCode:   9f
  BCP1: 00000003
  BCP2: 864CE558
  BCP3: 83736AE0
  BCP4: 85EAF878
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Helper files explaining the error:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\012214-24367-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-80855-0.sysdata.xml
```

Comment: Here someone has a similar issue: http://superuser.com/questions/412626/when-i-shut-down-windows-a-blue-screen-appears-and-says-dumping-physical-memor maybe it helps.

Comment: Likely a device driver bug, that Eclipse+Sleep just happen to be one such way to expose. If you open that .dmp file with WinDbg or just read the XML file, you will likely find the offending driver and it's call stack. Otherwise, just update all your device drivers to the latest certified versions.